# обработка изображений android

Tags: android, bitmap, drawbitmap

Требуется обработка изображений.

1) Имеется 27 PNG размера 1080х1080пх.

2) каждый нужно перекрасить в определенный цвет

3) затем все объединить в одно изображение. На выходе должен получиться PNG c альфа-каналом.

4) Цикл 1-3 повторяется для 6 изображений.

Через раз OutOfMemory. Делаю unusedBitmap.recycle() практически уже после каждого первого наложения одного из 27 изображений.

Вся работа в IntentService, исходные изображения в LruCache(memory/4), наложение через resultBitmap.drawBitmap(lruSourceBitmaps.get(number), x, y, paint).

Вопрос: какие существуют юзкейсы обработки больших изображений или множества изображений в андроиде?

Для себя пока вижу вариант записи промежуточного изображения на диск, очистка памяти, снова загрузка из файла промежуточного и т.д., но это будет cжирать ресурсы и огромное время на decodeResource на каждом шаге. Даже сейчас обработка занимает 10-20 секунд, а с промежуточным представить страшно :)